# Python, convert from ms to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am having a problem converting from ms to datetime. I get wrong datetime when printing.

I want to convert 1701092673 ms to datetime.

The result I am expecting is 2023-11-27 02:44:33

```
import datetime

ms = 1701092673
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (dt)
```

python prints
1970-01-20 17:31:32

I also tried the code below:

```
import datetime

ms = 1701092673
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print (dt)
```

Python prints
2023-11-27 14:44:33

Comment: The result datetime is in UTC. You probably have to convert the datetime object to your local timezone.

Comment: Remember that there is no such thing as "a datetime" without a timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect 12-hour time? Then change `%H` to `%I`:

```py
import datetime

ms = 1701092673
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S")
print(dt)
```

Prints:

```
2023-11-27 02:44:33
```

---

- `%I` - Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%H` - Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: I never thought of that, thanks! :D

Comment: lovely answer !  upvote.